# Box plot com desvio padrão

Tags: r

Preciso fazer um gráfico de boxplot com desvio padrão, mas não sei como faz isso em R.

Quero fazer para a biomassa captura e número de indivíduos em gráficos separados, se tiver como me dar um exemplo.

Comment: Acho que essa questão e a resposta podem te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254924/64969 ; minha ignorância em [tag:r] não me permite ir muito mais longe do que este presente comentário

Comment: Não percebo o que pretende com *um gráfico de boxplot com desvio padrão*. Os boxplots têm outra forma de mostrar a variabilidade dos dados, usam a distância interquartis, não o desvio-padrão. E, já agora, pode postar a saída de `dput(dados)` na pergunta? Se for muito grande, `dput(head(dados, 20))`.

Comment: Tecnicamente, é possível construir um boxplot com desvio padrão. Acho esquisito e pode levar o leitor a se confundir, caso isto não esteja explícito. Como o Rui falou, os boxplots são construídos com os quartis, que são uma medida de posição. Não entendo o que significaria colocar uma medida de dispersão como o desvio padrão no boxplot. Seria limitar a caixa dentro do intervalo (`Média - DesvioPadrão`; `Média - DesvioPadrão`), numa analogia ao intervalo (`Q_1`; `Q_3`) do boxplot tradicional? Enfim, é uma pergunta que necessita de mais esclarecimentos.

Comment: Se você realmente quer representar o desvio padrão e a média (imagino), considere um gráfico com barra de erros no lugar do boxplot.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai como se podem produzir gráficos de caixa-e-bigodes (*box-and-whiskers plots* ou *boxplots*) com a média como medida de tendência central e com o desvio-padrão como medida de variabilidade.

Primeiro, gerar os dados.

```
set.seed(1412)    # Torna o código reprodutível

n <- 1e3
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
```

Agora o boxplot de uma só variável, `x`. O truque é usar a saída de `boxplot`, que é uma lista, e modificar manualmente um dos membros dessa lista, o que dá as estatísticas do gráfico. Neste caso, `bp$stats`.

```
bp <- boxplot(x, plot = FALSE)

m <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
s <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
bp$stats[2, 1] <- m - s
bp$stats[3, 1] <- m
bp$stats[4, 1] <- m + s

bxp(bp)    # É esta função que desenha os boxplots
```

Agora o mesmo mas com várias variáveis. (Só duas, é fácil generalizar.)
O método é exatamente o mesmo, só mudam os cálculos das médias e desvios-padrões.

```
mat <- cbind(x, y)
bp2 <- boxplot(mat, plot = FALSE)

m2 <- colMeans(mat, na.rm = TRUE)
s2 <- apply(mat, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
bp2$stats[2, ] <- m2 - s2
bp2$stats[3, ] <- m2
bp2$stats[4, ] <- m2 + s2

bxp(bp2)
```